# Mastermind guessing

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, permutations, recreational-mathematics, book-recommendation

I'm reading this [problem](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=888#google_vignette) and I can understand how they got the output for the first four test cases. But the last one I can't really arrive at it. Is there some mathematical concept that I can apply to get to it instead of just writing a program that counts every permutation by brute force?

Also is there some book on combinatorics that can help me in these types of problems?

Comment: For a fully general solution, I would expect brute force programming to be intended.  For the very specific case of $n$ distinct elements, all of whom appear in the code but none in the correct position... this is called a "[Derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)."  There are $!5=44$ such derangements, as correctly noted in the linked problem.  Derangements should be covered in every introductory textbook on combinatorics, and even if not then certainly inclusion-exclusion principle would be which is an easy way to derive the formula for derangements.

Comment: Please [edit] your post so it is self-contained.  We want people to be able to understand what is being asked, without having to click on an external link, and we want the question to remain meaningful even if the link stops working.  This site is a place where people can collaborate to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others, so please try to make sure your question fits into that goal.